# Javascript development on Chromebook without installing Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, chromebook

I am thinking of getting a Chromebook and use it partially for *offline* Javascript development. I know about the options of dual boot Ubuntu or Crouton. But since Javascript is built in to browsers (I suppose the Chrome browser allows loading local .html? I am not sure as I don't use ChromeOS), I just want the basics:

1. A decent text editor for programming
2. Revision control, I suppose I can use Google Drive but git would be ideal.

Is it feasible without installing Ubuntu? Chromebook is only slightly cheaper than entry level Windows laptops so I want to know if there is simple Chromebook solution for my purpose.

Comment: having a text editor on a Chromebook isn't a problem.  Git will be the problem because of the ARM architecture unless your talking about a x86 Chromebook.

Comment: x86 Chromebooks are quite common now. I have no problem limiting my selection to Intel based Chromebooks. But what are my non-Ubuntu options?

Comment: You could just use ChromeOS.  It has text editors.

Answer (score 1):

Chromebooks offer text editors via Chrome Web Store. For example:

- [JSFiddlePlayer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsfiddle-player/acmoiaipblimhfnjejofmmfjkgpedcpd)
- [Frontest](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frontest/lkpidflkblcpnhpfdpgiabaadlfddmbd)
- [Clear Code](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-code/glnikohjhmkofkfcphgbdlmhjdjffcmg)
- [Code Plunker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-plunker-live-html-cs/llofhnpelgfcleglkkgfmpfohmlmkofe)

and any Git repo can be connected to via the [Secure Shell Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-extension/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd?hl=en).